# PHP IF message is not being printed

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a signup script with email confirmation and its working almost fine.
The users info is firstly sent from form to a "temp" table and when he follows the email confirmation link the info goes from "temp" table to "india" table, its final destination.

The confirmation link is a file called "confirmation.php".

Although the code is sending data from one table to the other, it is not printing the message "Obrigado, o seu registo foi validado.", portuguese for "Thanks, your registration was now validated". What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Confirmation.php

```
<?php
include_once ('config.php');

$confirm_code = $_GET["confirm_code"];

$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM temp WHERE confirm_code = '$confirm_code'");
$result1= mysqli_fetch_array($sql1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql1) == 1) {
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO india (confirm_code, name, password, email) SELECT confirm_code, name, password, email FROM temp WHERE confirm_code = '$confirm_code'");

    if($query) {
        $del = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM temp WHERE confirm_code = '$confirm_code'");
        if($del) {
            $msg = "Obrigado, o seu registo foi validado.";
        }    
    }   
} else {
    $msg2 = "Erro no registo";
}   
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please indent the php code it's unreadable like this.

Comment: If you're using mysqli functions, you may as well [bind your parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for security purposes instead of dumping variables haphazardly in the query.

Comment: You set two variables with the messages, but nothing prints out the values in this script.

Comment: You show part of code. Here nothing printed you only set variables. Also the variables are with different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM temp WHERE confirm_code = '$confirm_code'");`

in the if condition like this:( you missed to print i think)

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM temp WHERE confirm_code = '$confirm_code'"))`
{ 
  $msg = "Obrigado, o seu registo foi validado.";
 echo $msg;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to echo the `$msg` out outside of the `if` statement, as the `$msg` is set to something else if the isn't a successful registration.

Answer (score 1):

You should use instead of `if(mysqli_num_rows($sql1) == 1) {` the result variable: `if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) == 1) {`.

Please also use parametrized queries like explained in [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)